# Pandas group by and aggregate on custom function

Tags: pandas

Sample Pandas Dataframe:

```
Name Won
dan  N
dan  Y
jon  N
jon  N
jon  N
```

Desired final table :

```
Name Won
dan  Y
jon  N
```

Basically I want to check if someone won atleast once. How do I do this with group_by and aggregate?

Comment: Your question and outcome do not agree in the english sense of it. Please edit either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `'Y' > 'N'` evaluates to `True` you can take the `max` within name.

```
df.groupby('Name')['Won'].max()

#Name
#dan    Y
#jon    N
#Name: Won, dtype: object
```

---

For situations with multiple categories where simple string sorting doesn't work use an ordered CategoricalDtype and still take the max.

```
import pandas as pd

my_cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['N', 'Y'], ordered=True)
df['Won'] = df['Won'].astype(my_cat)

df.groupby('Name')['Won'].max()
```

Comment: thanks! It seems like quite an expensive operation, takes my quite some time with 2M rows

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
df.groupby('Name').sum().Won.str.contains('Y').replace({True:'Y', False:'N'})
```

Output:

```
Name
dan    Y
jon    N
Name: Won, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what will give you an outcome that indicates if someone won atleast once.

```
df[df.groupby(['Name'])['Won'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('Y').any())]




 Name Won
0  dan   N
1  dan   Y
```